# keep input dates in text boxes through jquery Date picker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I want to keep values in text fields after getting reports. textboxes have default current date but can be assigned a new value through jquery datepicker. so when i  select a date(e.g 27/10/2015) it should remain in textbox after getting reports. Problem is when i search records values reset to current date. can anyone help?

```
<input runat="server" id="txtstartDate" type="text"   />
<input runat="server" id="txtFinishDate" type="text"  />
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#txtstartDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        $("#txtFinishDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    });
});
```

Comment: show some code..

Comment: @Saif edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i am answering my own question. So according to my requirements i have to populate current date as default value and than have to select date from datepicker if required. and also i have to retain values after getting report. so, First i changed

```
<input runat="server" id="txtstartDate" type="text"   />
<input runat="server" id="txtFinishDate" type="text"  />
```

to

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtstartDate" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFinishDate" />
```

and then populated these text boxes at page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack )
        { 
            txtstartDate.Text =   DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            txtFinishDate.Text = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
    }
```

and in jquery i just defind datepicker for these two files.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$='txtstartDate']").datepicker();
        $("[id$='txtFinishDate']").datepicker();
    });


</script>
```

This is how i figured out the solution. hopefully it might be helpful for anyone else.

Comment: Isn't it same as my code except you set default date time server side?

Comment: and yes thats the whole point now instead of initializing date in jquery i am now initializing on server side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `ViewState`. It retrieves your values after post back. When you are generating report, you are posting these values and you are not getting them back because you used `html` control. You should use `Asp.Net` controls to take advantage of `ViewState`. You just need to change

```
<input runat="server" id="txtstartDate" type="text"   />
<input runat="server" id="txtFinishDate" type="text"  />
```

to

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtstartDate" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFinishDate" />
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#txtstartDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        $("#txtFinishDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    });
});
```

by

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        if($("[id$='txtstartDate']").val() == "")
            $("[id$='txtstartDate']").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        if($("[id$='txtFinishDate']").val() == "")
            $("[id$='txtFinishDate']").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but sorry it didn't work. its setting current date. i have already changed html to asp control and  even after changing jquery function, it sets current dates. Can you please suggest any thing else. i will be very thankful

Comment: `$("[id$='txtstartDate']").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());` this is setting current date. Why do you need these lines?

Comment: Its a requirement that by default value should be current date. and if someone want to select different dates than he would be able to select different dates from date picker.

Comment: it does retain values but after getting report if i again click in input fields datepicker doesnot pop up

Comment: Where are you initializing data picker?

Comment: i changed the html input to asp textbox and initialized the value from server side code on page load. thats how i resolved this issue.